# Listadapter not binding values to listview

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listadapter

i created a demo app to display the list of products on screen. the product list comes from remote server. in the logs i can see the data coming and being stored in the arralist but somehow it is not binding with list view. i am making the http call in the background using async class.

below is the activity on create code

```
   ListAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dbtest2_all_products);
    Log.i("Entrey level=","entere dbtest2allproducts class");
    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
   new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = new ListView(DBtest2AllProducts.this);

    // updating listview
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

below is postexecute method of

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
    // ((BaseAdapter) adapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("before adapter",productsList.toString());
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                DBtest2AllProducts.this, productsList,
                R.layout.activity_dbtest2_list_items, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                        TAG_NAME},
                new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name }); 
            //setAdapter(adapter);
```

though i believe as there is some sync issue with the setAdapter(adapter) step but i since i am new to android so couldn't bet on it. i tried calling setAdapter(adapter) method and adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() withing the postexecute method but both of them throw error saying "method is not defined for this type" However if i cast adapter to (BaseAdapter) then adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't throw any error but i actully dont know what difference does this casting make and also casting didn't work as well.

Below is log cat

```
I/before adapter(32729): [{pid=1, name=iphone 4s}, {pid=2, name=samsung}]
```

Please suggest if you see any issues with the code. Thanks for helping in advance.

below are the xml layouts

```
all_product.xml

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/pid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

  <!-- Name Label -->
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="20dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: move lv.setAdapter(adapter); in onPostExecute, after adapter = new SimpleAdapter(...

Comment: i tried that but it throws error "lv cannot be resolved" i think lv is out of scope for post execute method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize you adapter before setting it to the `ListView`. Make ListView global and set the adapter only after getting the data

```
    ListView lv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dbtest2_all_products);
        Log.i("Entrey level=","entere dbtest2allproducts class");
        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get list view from xml file 
        lv = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        FrameLayout rootView = (FrameLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

        //Add this line to make sure your list is using the whole screen width
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rootView.addView(lv);
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            DBtest2AllProducts.this, productsList,
            R.layout.activity_dbtest2_list_items, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                    TAG_NAME},
            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name }); 
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos ! i guess you skipped my last lines in the question. i tried adapter.notifyDataSetChange() in post execute but it throws error saying "the method is undefined for type listAdapter" and i tried second solution. though it didnt raise any error but still after the dialog box disapperas , i dont see the list of products :(

Comment: any idea why notifyDataSetChange() not working in post execute ?

Comment: I think I found your problem. Is your ListView on the activity_dbtest2_all_products.xml file? If it is then you are not initializing properly and if you are adding it programmatically then you also need to add it to the main view. That's why you aren't able to see anything

Comment: Thanks Carlos, the second solution worked. However it would have been great if i could use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method but i think it is available for baseadaper class only as it doesnt appear automatcially for adapter(please correct me if i am wrong). i am using 2 xml files . first for all_products activity which i set as content in oncreate methode. it has only a listview element in it. another xml files explains how data would be displayed for each list item which i passed in adapter instantiation "activity_dbtest2_list_items.xml". Thanks for your help :)

Comment: btw framLayout causes the list to stick to the left corner though i have used android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" and android:gravity="center_horizontal" in my code. is it because of framelayout and if there is any way my text appear in center horizontal ?

Comment: If your `ListView` is already on the xml file then you can remove this: FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    rootLayout.addView(lv); that will also solve the alignment problem

Comment: if i remove the FrameLayout then i dont see the list

Comment: Can you post your all_products.xml?

Comment: Answer updated! Check the part where gets the listView from xml

Comment: the updated solution doesn't work... i guess, though the list_item.xml is attached with adapter in postexecute the code   "rootLayout.addView(lv);" is necessary to inflater it in current activity's layout !

Comment: It shouldn't be. Did you declare ListView outside of your `onCreate` method?

Comment: yeah...even in your second solution it is above onCreate method !

Comment: Weird.. can you try one more thing? I just made some changes to my answer. See if that works. Also I got rid of the first part of the answer since the adapter won't take `notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Sorry Carlos but that didn't work too... i think you should update your ans with the one that worked for me so that it can help others as well..

Comment: My last suggestion would be to try using a different adapter. Make your own implementation of `BaseAdapter` and see how that works. 
I'll modify my answer to your request

Comment: sure..just a starter and lots there to learn :) ...Thanks Carlos

Comment: No problem, answer updated and I added an extra line to make the alignment of your list be the desired one

Comment: Hey Carlos, can you help me with one more issue ?...please check the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/27255161/4290220    ..thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

@Pawan Rawat, after implementing the above answer, and if your confident in carrying on, switch to Volley, a networking library which is more robust, performance network calls faster with less code.
Please read more at http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: Thanks Trey, i will surely have a look at it once i am done resolving the issue in hand !