# android app reacts properly to to phone's back button but crashes with nulpointerexception when clicked on menu's back button

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, listactivity, application-restart

i have an activity (say A2) which gets an id from its parent activity (say A1) and after fetching results from database prepares a list. on clicking a list item it passes the another id to a child activity (say A3) for further processing.Now when i come back from A3 to A2 using phone's native back button everything is awesome and i see the data on A2 but if i use the app's menu bar back button the app crashes giving nullpointerexception. i am putting the code below for reference...

Activity A2

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_classes);

    class_details = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    TextView tv_institute_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.allclassess_schoolname);
    //List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    Log.d("inside oncreate","inside oncreate");
    // prepairing the alert builder for application alert messages
    alertbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AllClasses.this);

    // retreiving data from intent
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String imessage_string = b.getString("imessage");

    try  // preparing params for asynctask
    {
        imessage_json = new JSONObject(imessage_string);
        teacher_id=imessage_json.getString("teacherid");
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teacherid",teacher_id));
        //Log.d("in allclasses, params",params.toString());

    }catch(JSONException e){
        //Log.d("json exception ","excepiton");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    new getAllClassess().execute(params); // asynctask called and set adapter to lv

    lv = new ListView(context);

    // Add list programmatically
    FrameLayout rootLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(android.R.id.content);
     rootLayout.setFocusable(true);
     rootLayout.addView(lv);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) { 
            Map map = new HashMap<String,String>();


            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String cid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.classid)).getText()
                    .toString();
           // String teacher_id=params.get(0).getValue("teacherid");
            map.put("classid", cid);
            map.put("teacherid", teacher_id);

            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(map);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("imessage", j.toString()); 

          //  String[] imessage_array = {cid,teacher_id};


            Intent i= new Intent(context,ClassRecordingDetails.class);

           // i.putExtra("imessage", imessage_array);
            i.putExtras(b);
            startActivity(i);
        }

protected void onRestart(){
    super.onRestart();

    Log.d("inside restart","restarted");
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("inside onresume","resumed");
}
```

Activity A3 : as of now nothing i am performing on A3

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_class_recording_details);

    //Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String imessage_string= b.getString("imessage");
    Log.d("in recording details",imessage_string);
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      Intent homeIntent = new Intent(context, AllClasses.class);
      homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      homeIntent.putExtras(b);
      //startActivity(homeIntent); 
      NavUtils.navigateUpTo(getParent(), homeIntent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
```

Cat Log

```
12-03 02:49:19.144: D/AndroidRuntime(3625): Shutting down VM
12-03 02:49:19.144: W/dalvikvm(3625): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f69d40)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625): Process: com.example.rrd.school.project, PID: 3625
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.support.v4.app.NavUtilsJB.navigateUpTo(NavUtilsJB.java:33)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils$NavUtilsImplJB.navigateUpTo(NavUtils.java:120)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpTo(NavUtils.java:202)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at com.example.rrd.school.project.ClassRecordingDetails.onOptionsItemSelected(ClassRecordingDetails.java:47)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2608)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:167)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-03 02:49:19.157: E/AndroidRuntime(3625):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 02:49:28.898: I/Process(3625): Sending signal. PID: 3625 SIG: 9
12-03 02:49:30.236: I/httpresponse(4242): org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@428f80c8
12-03 02:49:30.238: I/json_string_block=(4242): {"classdetails":[{"classid":"1","classname":"12th C"},{"classid":"2","classname":"12th B"},{"classid":"3","classname":"12th A"}],"success":1,"instituteid":"inst1","institutename":"instname1","teacherid":"teacher1","teachername":"teachername"}
12-03 02:49:30.243: I/class_details=(4242): [{classname=12th C, classid=1}, {classname=12th B, classid=2}, {classname=12th A, classid=3}]
```

any help to resolve the issue is greatly appreciated...thanks !

Comment: Can you post the whole log of the error you are getting?

Comment: i have added the Log cat. what happen is when i click the up button on A3 to go to A2 firs i receive the message "project stopped working" then A2 makes an AsyncTask call and data is feeded in the list. Weired thing is none of the log msgs Log.d("inside "method") gets printed which i have put inside onCreate, onRestart and onResume.

Comment: Is a2 declared as a3's parent in your manifest?

Comment: @Meet , yeah.. sorry for confusion A3->class_recording_details and A2->AllClasses     ... <activity
            android:name=".ClassRecordingDetails"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_class_recording_details"
            android:parentActivityName=".AllClasses" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.rrd.school.project.AllClasses" />
        </activity>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay...so it worked out. i had to set the launchMode=singleTop property inside the manifest file for activity A2(allclasses) like below so that system keeps instance created for A2 activity alive in backstack

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

and then just call navUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this) method from activity A3 to call the same instance from the backstack instead of creating a new instance.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
}
```

hmm...simple solution haa...:D ... Thanks guys for your help... !!

Answer (score 0):

Try
`getParentActivityIntent()` instead of `getParent()`

Comment: code updated to *** homeIntent= NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(getParent());
       homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      // homeIntent.putExtras(b);
       
       Log.d("near homeintent",b.toString()); 
       NavUtils.navigateUpTo(getParent(), homeIntent);*** but i still get the error...difference is that this time i got "inside oncreated" and inside "onResume" got printed. However i was expecting "inside onRestart" and "inside onResumed"

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: yeah...so logically coming back should be calling onRestart()  but since i am getting error "project stopped working" so my current app process is getting killed hence calling onCreate()... that makes sense ...